# ¿Como recargar una libreria Python sin que el servidor Flask se interrumpa?

Tags: html, python, flask

Tengo una pagina web con python y flask. En la base de datos tengo una lista de nombres de objetos "Frutas" que se muestran en un select de html para que la persona elija el nombre y la cantidad de fruta, eso es en el formulario 1, por otro lado tengo un formualario 2 para agregar nuevas frutas tanto a la base de datos como a mi propia libreria y efectivamente lo hace, crea el archivo con la respectiva clase, pero al intentar actualizar la lista de frutas me dice que "Melocoton no es un nombre valido".

Pienso que pasa porque el objeto nuevo esta creado en un archivo pero no ha sido invocado al globals actual, intente agregarlo con   `globals()["Melocoton"] = eval("libreria.modulo.archivo.Melocoton")` y me sigue diciendo que dentro de libreria no hay ningun modulo "archivo".

intente con importlib y la pantalla queda en negro y se interrumpe el servidor de python-flask

despues que se reinicia el servidor todos los datos se leen correctamente, asi que la pregunta seria: ¿Como recargo la libreria sin detener el proceso del servidor de flask- python?

Comment: Muy seguramente vas por el camino equivocado, no me ha quedado del todo claro tu problema. Serviría si colocaras tu código en la pregunta para poder hacernos una idea o probarlo en el mejor de los casos.

Comment: ¿Cómo un objeto de negocio (Melocotón) requiere su propia Clase? Creo que lo estás entendiendo al revés. Melocotón es una Fruta, por lo tanto es un tipo de objeto de la Clase Fruta. No veo porqué debes crear una Clase para Melocotón, y mucho menos porqué debes crear un fichero para guardar esta Clase. Por favor considera agregar un [mcve] para poder aclarar más tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por la perspectiva, efectivamente analizando el problema de esa manera lo que hice fue: 

Cada vez que alguien quiera crear una fruta, en vez de crear un archivo  -clase "Melocoton" o "Banana" lo mejor es que sea instancia de Fruta y guardar en la base de datos una constante FRUTAS que contenga el diccionario `{{"nombre":"Melocoton", "semilla":True}, {"nombre":"Banana", "semilla":False}}` y cuando el usuario pida "3 melocotones", hacer una instancia de fruta con ese nombre y cantidad y que en la base de datos busque si tiene semilla o no